# Restrict SSH tunnel to specific user

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've opened an ssh tunnel on my gateway like this:

```
autossh -M 30000 -f -N example.com -L \*:20022:192.168.1.40:22
```

How can I make a user, let's say John, to only use this ssh tunnel and restrict all other users that I have so no user except John can ssh using port 20022? Please note that user john doesn't exist on my gateway, whether as a local user or in the LDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client is a Linux host, you can do it with [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --dest 192.168.1.40 --dport 22 -m owner --uid-owner john -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dest 192.168.1.40 --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Note that this conditions on the destination address and port, not the source port 20022. If you really want to restrict access on just that one source port, then you can use `--sport 20022` instead of `--dest` and `--dport`. But of course that won't stop another user from opening a similar tunnel on a different port.

Answer (score 1):

Publish only John's public key to the authorized_keys file on the gateway. Turn of pw auth.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, turning off password authentication isn't an option.

Comment: Publishing only John's key and turning off pw auth, will restrict all ssh access to John, not just ssh tunnelling, which is the what the question requires.